# POST-able image drop-down menu

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using this HTML and jQuery code to make images as selection options of a drop-down menu, but I'm unsure how I can make the values POST-able like you can with a standard text selection drop-down.  The code is being used for a checklist website I'm making, so the images are of a checkmark and an X.

One of my attempts to make it POST was to add `method="POST"` and `onclick="<?php $checkVar01='check'; ?>` or `onclick="<?php $checkVar01='x'; ?>"` to the two a tags, but it was essentially pointless as it only seems to output the 'x' value every time, even without clicking the a tag.  I'm using AJAX to POST the values to another page.

```
<table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="4" id="timestamp">
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Do something</td>
            <td>
              <div class="btn-group" style="margin:0px;">
                <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Select<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="<?php $checkVar01='check'; ?>">OK <img src="../images/green_check.png" width="25em"/></a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="<?php $checkVar01='check'; ?>">NOK <img src="../images/x.png"  width="25em"/></a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td><input id="comment01" type="text" class="form-control form-control-md" maxlength="50"></td>
          </tr>

<script>

  $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
    var selText = $(this).text();
    var imgSource = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    var img = '<img src="' + imgSource + '" width="20em"/>';
    $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText + ' ' + img + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
  });

$("#homeSubmitButton").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../actions.php?action=submitForm",
      data: "&checkVar01=" + <?php echo $checkVar01; ?> + "&comment01=" + $("#comment01").val(),
      success: function(result) {
        alert("Your checksheet has been submitted!");
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not an advice forum, it's a code Q&A site. You should first attempt to do the POST and show your attempt so we can help you fix it.

Comment: Fair enough I guess.  I didn't include my attempts because I felt they going down the wrong path, but perhaps I could've added something.

Comment: Yes, definitely include your best attempt, what you want it to do and what's it's actually doing. It's way easier to give help when you know what you're dealing with.

Comment: My thought was to either manipulate the a tags somehow to react when an option is clicked or to figure it out using script, but after some research I'm still not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML already has a checkbox form element. You can style check boxes (and radio buttons) using the `:checked` pseudo selector to appear almost any way you want.

https://paulund.co.uk/style-checkboxes-with-css

Since you're using real checkboxes, you can put them inside a proper form. You can then either submit that form normally, or have [jQuery serialize the form](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and send those values to your server via an [AJAX request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work by changing the a tag href and the AJAX POST data as follows:

```
<a href="javascript: var checkVar01='check';"><img src="../images/green_check.png" width="25em"/></a>
```

data

```
data: "&checkVar01=" + checkVar01 + "&comment01=" + $("#comment01").val(),
```